# How can I parse oa#[code] as an endpoint url in a .NET api?

Tags: .net, api, oauth

I would like to have SSO with my Oculus app and a .NET api.

In the documentation here https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/ps-account-linking/

It says that they will send the token to the example
https://someloginuri.com/oa#1234ImCiAib3JnLXNjb3BlZF9pZCI6ICIxMjM0NTY3ODEyMzQ1Njc4Igp9

(Where https://someloginuri.com/oa is the value you provided in the previous step, and the part after the # is the base 64 text of the json you need.)

My question is how do I set up my .net endpoint so that /oa is the endpoint name, and the bit after # is the parameter?

Do I need to use middleware to do this?